# Why is almost every word misspelled?

Tags: orthography

Why is almost every word misspelled? Considering, the fact that a sound should be represented by a single symbol or letter. So, I do not get confused spelling and its easy for a person to become literate.

Comment: Because we value being able to read old books more than the inconvenience of not having a fully phonemic writing system. But some countries have at times reasoned the other way had introduced spelling reforms.

Comment: i get that and your ability to do so should not be taken from you but the individual sounds we make make you express something and when you put them together you express somthing different but relative to the individual sounds you make and their meaning should not be ignored because those are our natural expressions this is really to much to say on this site thats why i asked such a difficult question

Comment: No, individual sounds don't have meaning separate from words, except for rare examples of [phonesthemes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonestheme). Even then it's consonant clusters, not individual sounds.

Comment: And note when you say old your saying with in hundreds of years when the earth is over 4 billions years old and life is theoretically in the range of 2-3 billion years old no telling how old humans and human like animals are chimpanzees have the exact same brain structure but fully matured adults only achieve a brain size about the size of a 7 year old modern human and what we call neanderthals had slightly larger brains than us

Comment: Eye all ways use spell cheque when eye use my pee sea. It marques for my revue miss steaks eye can knot sea. Plane lea it is use full, wye knot try it two.

Answer (score 1):

"Misspelled" is a tricky word. It assumes there's some gold standard we can compare against that tells us if something is spelled correctly or not. And for English, there's no government body legislating whether the new slang term for "throw" is spelled *yeet* or *yete* or *yeat*. (Some other languages have these sorts of government bodies, but how effective they actually are in practice is debatable.)

Instead, the standard for an English word to be "spelled correctly" is that *the vague global consensus of English-speakers accepts it as correct*. That is, when people started using a new slang term for "throw", *yeet* is the convention that caught on, and thus it is the "correct" spelling.

> Considering, the fact that a sound should be represented by a single symbol or letter. So, I do not get confused spelling and its easy for a person to become literate.

The unsatisfying answer is, the vague global consensus of English-speakers seems to value our old spelling traditions more than we value unambiguity. Other languages' orthographies have been overhauled before, so it's not utterly impossible; English is just such a widespread language at this point, that keeping everything consistent turns out to be really useful.

Comment: The word reasoned is also tricky because people follow trends and and listen to people that play their beliefs to get them to fight their causes but i get your perspective but their is only one real reality though the entirety of it is impossible for an individual to see the problem is that language being written around your beliefs making your beliefs sound better than human emotions our words are our barks and only we can understand them the perspective your speaking from requires to many words for me to respond to but but language should reflect human emotion not trends and what sounds good

Comment: @DonnyMartinez Language is something that evolves, not something that's designed; saying language "should" be different is sort of like saying frogs "should" have gills. Maybe gills would be useful, maybe not, but either way, the frogs are doing just fine without them—and nothing I do is likely to ever change that.

Comment: So when you say the sound ee makes in cheese you dont smile and if you say ve using the sounds those letters are supposed to represent in this alphabet you dont express hate you think human language is new its most likely been evolving far before we think humans have been around we evolved from somthing our natural evolution and the language that evolved with it is long lost their is only one real reality and people like you are stopping us from figuring it out and that will result in the failure of modern day man because of the imaginary languages i have to use my imagination to make it real

Comment: @DonnyMartinez Languages which follow Saussure's principle of arbitrariness (that there's no inherent, universal meaning to individual sounds) have been around for millennia—we have direct evidence going back at least six thousand years, and it doesn't seem to have caused any problems in all that time.

Comment: @DonnyMartinez Sorry, I still have no idea what you're trying to say. Linguistics has been a rigorous science for about a century now, even by a conservative estimate. The principle of arbitrariness has stood up to scrutiny for all that time without any significant counterexample.

Comment: Actually it causes lots of problems for 1 war because we cant communicate and the different imaginary languages create different false realities that cause conflicts between different civilizations 2 it does not allow a person to express they have to use a made up word for an emotion and human emotion is very complex and their are more emotions than we have words for them and this is a huge part of why so many people develop psychological problems

Comment: And to say the single sounds have no meaning is the same thing as saying your facial expressions have no meaning

Comment: Even geneticist have tried to trace our genetics back and it dead ends at 1 woman so that means we are clones and humanity is far older than we think and it would just take a mass extinction event or enough time for evidence of them to be erased so for many reasons i do not trust the current beliefs and theories around mankind

Answer (score 1):

Since we can know a word from its pronunciation without being able to spell it, it is evident that we remember words and their pronunciations in a way that does not correspond exactly to the way they are spelled in a conventional alphabetic writing system like our Roman based system.  But this should be obvious, anyhow, from the facts that (1) not all literate people use or even know an alphabetic writing system, and (2) the alphabetic spelling system was not worked out until around 800 bce, long after the time of the oldest languages, spoken and written, that we can reconstruct.

Then too, the most basic phonetic forms of words in modern phonological theories do not resemble their alphabetic spellings at all.